# Why are my divs in a WP template nesting?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I created a template for a wordpress site and my divs are nesting. The code is working in my [codepen](https://codepen.io/developedbydavid/pen/7926c9f71c1360dd124f56365aeac8ec), but when I run it with a custom post type it nests them. I have read that it is sometimes because of open divs, which makes sense, but I don't see any. Has anyone ever experienced this or see any issues?

```
<?php
get_header();
//the_content();
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'patterns'
);
$patterns = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $patterns->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while( $patterns->have_posts() ) : $patterns->the_post() ?>
            <div class="image_hover_appear <?php $categories = get_the_category( $patterns->ID, 'category' );
                foreach( $categories as $category ) {
                    echo $category->slug . ' ';
                } ?>">
                <div class="appear_container">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <div class="appear_content">
                        <div class="appear_title">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="appear_desc">
                            <!--This is the description-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="appear_link" data-fancybox ></a>
                    <div class="appear_overlay"></div>
                    <div class="appear_border-top"></div>
                    <div class="appear_border-bottom"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile ?>
<?php endif ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Try looking at the raw html that's being put out(ctrl+u in your browser) to see where the open div could be. Maybe run in through a linter to help you locate it.

Comment: @SessionCookieMonster I removed the closing div. That did not change the nesting behavior though. No luck with linter. Any other ideas? I'm currently commenting out all but first two divs and attempting to isolate the issue. I overwrote the file on the server but am noticing no change in the files the browser is serving. Deleted cache and disabled it in web dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with astra theme and my child theme. I added my custom template's code into the archive.php file and finally got a change in the layout. The problem was not what it seemed.

Answer (score 0):

There is minor error in your code. I can see that you have closed one div outside of your while loop but you have not opened div before while loop. so, add div or remove closed div from bottom.

Comment: Yes, there is. Thanks for that. I have deleted the closing div tag, and updated the code above, but it still is nesting the divs inside each other. Any other ideas?